# Exp-resso won't show states when US is only country

Tags: expresso-store

I only want to sell products to US residents. From the Exp-resso admin panel, I've set the United States to be the only enabled country.

However, when I set up the billing form ( I'm using store_example/checkout2 ) I can't access any states from the state  .

Seems like Exp-resso store is using JavaScript to populate the state select tag after you make a country selection. However, when there is only one country, the change isn't registering.

Setting a default country & state isn't making a difference either ( no matter how many countries are enabled ).

[image: Store admin settings]

Comment: When you look at the console are you getting any JS errors? What version of Store are you using and what version of EE?

Comment: Very strange. It's working fine for me now. I don't recall seeing a JS console error at the time it wasn't working. 

Using version 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments:

> Very strange. It's working fine for me now. I don't recall seeing a JS console error at the time it wasn't working.

Generally Store does update the select menu with states when you change the country, but this also happens once on page load, so I'm not sure why this wasn't working for you.

If you come across it in future, check for JS errors in your browser's error console - it often comes down to something like jQuery not being loaded, or other errors on the page causing Store's JS not to run.